# Why isn't my pink color mask returning a continuous shape

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to create a line tracking program with a drone with a forward facing camera.  I understood this could be a bit difficult since the camera was not facing downward and would pick up on the environment.  I need it to face forward for a face recognition algorithm.  So I chose to make the line pink.  I found on this site some parameters for color filtering.  I thought they would be over compensating with the color range, but the tape doesn't show up in a full sheet, but rather in a ton of boxes inside the tape.

```py
def pinkThreshold(image):
    copy = image.copy()
    copy = cv2.cvtColor(copy,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    lower_pink = np.array([125,30,100])
    upper_pink = np.array([225,255,255])
    pinkImage = cv2.inRange(copy, lower_pink, upper_pink)
    edges = cv2.Canny(pinkImage,240,255)
    return edges
```

The image I get is this:
[image]
I think it might have to do with the camera returning red squares, but i'm not completely sure what I should do about this and if this is even the issue.  The red pattern areas seem to be like what I have seen, but i'm not completely sure.  If that is true, what would be a good color filter with pink and red?  Also, would this be solved by a large floodlight over the line to be tracked?

The camera is attached to a DJI Tello drone.  I can't change the equipment.

Comment: The input image has very poor color fidelity, likely because of poor lighting conditions. If you zoom in you’ll see yellow, orange, red and even purple patches in the pink area. This causes your color detection to fail. You could apply a strong blur to the image first, but I don’t know if that will be enough. Better illumination is definitely a solution.

Comment: I did find some better illumination and that does help.  I worry a bit about getting strong enough lighting throughout the space for the line following.  It seems I need a lightbulb directly over all the tape.  What is the color frequency for red in HSV?  It might not hurt to have that in the range to include with contours.  Or possibly would yellow be a better color to use since it is not a composite color like pink or orange?

Comment: Hsv hue is circular, so you might need to have 2 ranges, one around 0 and one around 360° (which is value 180 in opencv). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29162813/2393191 about how to shift the hue to center it around one target value, which makes setting a range easier (but might be more expensive in total).

Comment: Check the inRange result before applying canny, for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it might have to do with the camera returning red squares, but i'm not completely sure what I should do about this and if this is even the issue.

Let's adjust contrast and use color substitution to see the actual problem:

[image]

As you can see, color noise is huge. If you try to do color-based segmentation or try to apply any other "color sensitive logic" by targeting any specific color you are going to see that noise being picked up:

[image]

You can always improve your lighting conditions and extend the range you defined, but there is another approach: you can use multiple colors to find the actual shape you need, you can use thresholding to boost some specific areas and so on:

[image]

Long story short:

- improve lightning conditions
- AND/OR do some specific preprocessing with wider color range to properly address noise and overall quality of the picture